# CSS Не отрабатывает transform: scaleX(0)

Tags: html, css, transform

Есть такой шаблон CSS/HTML

```css
.block_navigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border-right: 1px solid #2c2a37;
  background-color: #1f1d2c;
  z-index: 10
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .block_navigation {
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px
  }
  .block_navigation+* {
    margin-left: 5px
  }
}

.bl_nav__text {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  align-self: flex-start;
  color: #ababab;
  display: none
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .bl_nav__text {
    display: block
  }
}

.btn_menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #1292f0;
  background: 0 0;
  order: -1;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2
}

.btn_menu:after {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 18px;
  z-index: 3
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .btn_menu {
    display: none
  }
}

.bl_nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .bl_nav {
    padding-top: 0;
    width: initial
  }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) and (min-height: 600px) {
  .bl_nav {
    height: 95%
  }
}

.bl_nav__list {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 135px)
}

@media (max-width: 450px) and (min-height: 600px) {
  .bl_nav__list {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 170px)
  }
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

.bl_nav .menu-item:last-child,
.menu-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .menu-item {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0
  }
}

.bl_nav__link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .15s ease-in;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.bl_nav__link:focus,
.bl_nav__link:hover {
  color: #69c5ff
}

.bl_nav__link:after,
.bl_nav__link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}

.bl_nav__link:before {
  background-color: #373443;
  border-radius: 6px
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .bl_nav .bl_nav__link span {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bl_nav__link span {
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  /*  Почему это не работает */
}

.bl_nav__link.active {
  color: #69c5ff
}

.btn_menu__checkbox:checked~.bl_nav .bl_nav__link span {
  overflow: initial;
  display: revert;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  background-color: #373443;
}

.btn_menu__checkbox:checked~.bl_nav span {
  display: block;
}

.bl_nav .menu-item:last-child .bl_nav__link {
  font-size: 17px;
}

.btn_nav__mobil {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1eaf0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  top: 6px;
  right: 17px
}

.btn_nav__mobil:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
  background-position: -50px -32px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 6px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .2s ease-in;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .btn_nav__mobil {
    display: none;
  }
}

.block_tab__item a {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #2a3c90;
}

.block_tab__item a:focus,
.block_tab__item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn_navigation {
  display: block;
}

.btn_menu__checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .btn_menu__checkbox {
    display: none;
  }
}

.btn_menu__checkbox:checked+.block_navigation {
  transform: translateX(1);
}

.btn_menu__checkbox:checked~.btn_menu::after {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
  background-position: 0 -23px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_navigation">
  <p class="bl_nav__text">Рубрика</p>
  <input class="btn_menu__checkbox" id="topmenu" type="checkbox" aria-label="">
  <nav class="bl_nav">
    <ul class="bl_nav__list">
      <li class="icon-it menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent"><a href="/it-tehnology/" class="bl_nav__link"><span>IT tehnology</span></a></li>
      <li class="icon-jokes menu-item"><a href="/jokes/" class="bl_nav__link"><span>Jokes</span></a></li>
      <li class="icon-authors menu-item"><a href="/author/" class="bl_nav__link"><span>Autors</span></a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label class="btn_menu" for="topmenu"></label>
</div>
```

Подскажите, почему не отрабатывает свойство

```
.bl_nav__link span {
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

Идея в том, что бы в мобильной адаптации, только нажав на "псевдокнопку" отображались подписи к иконкам навигации. Не понимаю почему `transform: scaleX(0);` не скрывает мне эти надписи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` применяется только к [**transformable** элементам](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element). Это почти что угодно, кроме нескольких исключений. В частности исключением являются элементы у которых `inline`-овая блочная модель. Поскольку вы `span`-у ничего не задавали, то у него такая и есть.

Одно из простых решений, задать ему `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Спасибо. Неожиданно